# How to paste formula into model.matrix function in R?

Tags: r, model.matrix

By way of simplified example, say you have the following data:

```
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(n, 3, 1), x2 = rnorm(n, 0, 1))
```

And you wish to create a model matrix of the following form:

```
model.matrix(~ df$x1 + df$x2)
```

or more preferably:

```
model.matrix(~ x1 + x2, data = df)
```

but instead by pasting the formula into `model.matrix`. I have experimented with the following but encounter errors with all of them:

```
form1 <- "df$x1 + df$x2"
model.matrix(~ as.formula(form1))
model.matrix(~ eval(parse(text = form1)))
model.matrix(~ paste(form1))
model.matrix(~ form1)
```

I've also tried the same with the more preferable structure:

```
form2 <- "x1 + x2, data = df"
```

Is there a direct solution to this problem? Or is the `model.matrix` function not conducive to this approach?

Comment: Is there reason not to just use `model.matrix(~ ., df)`?

Comment: Ideally yes, the data frame contains a lot of columns that are not explanatory variables.

Comment: Subset the data in the call: `model.matrix(~ ., df[c("x1", "x2")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
expr <- "~ x1 + x2"
model.matrix(as.formula(expr), df)
```

You need to give `df` as the `data` argument outside of `as.formula`, as the `data` argument defines the environment within which to evaluate the formula.

If you don't want to specify the `data` argument you can do

```
model.matrix(as.formula("~ df$x1 + df$x2"))
```

Comment: yes thank you, annoyed at myself for not playing with around with the tilde.